# searchform not working in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

ok i have a problem with the search i'm creating a new blog in wordpress and it's not working at all i tried a lot and nothing change

this is the header.php code

```
    <div class="navbar-r">

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
  <input class="in-s-n" type="text" name="s" <?php the_search_query();?> />
  <input class="su-s-n" type="submit" value="Find" />
  </form>


  </div>
  <!--End navbar-r-->
```

and when i search the page get blank

what do i have to do? any help

Comment: how would this work without PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
<div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
</div>
```

For more details, check out this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form